# SWF: render fragments does not render

Tags: spring-webflow

I am using SWF, and in one view I have a table. Calling some actions, this table content changes in the database, so it should show different values on the interface. These values, include a checkbox, which remains checked after running the action.

This is my code, following the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#event-handlers-render):

**flow.xml**

```
<transition on="someTransition" to="overview">
            <evaluate expression="bean.someAction(someValue)" />
            <render fragments="tableForm" /> <!--I have also tried tableForm:row -->
        </transition>
```

**page.jsp**

```
<form:form method="POST" id="tableForm">
     <display:table id="row">
           <display:column title="">
            <form:checkbox path="chosenIds" value="${row.id}"/>
          </display:column>
          <display:column title="Value to change">
            <c:out value="${row.changedValue}"/>
        </display:column>
          <display:footer>
            <div class="tableFooter" >
                <input type="submit" name="_eventId_someTransition" value="Send" processIds="*"/>
            </div>
        </display:footer>
      </display:table>
  </form:form>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why -1? At least a reason could be given!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial updates don't work  for the forms I think. It will work on all output panels whether it is core jsf, primefaces or a4j.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html

Good Reference Project spring-webflow-2.3.1.RELEASE\projects\spring-webflow-samples\booking-faces bundled with spring release

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I really need to make a new search in order to retrieve the new values from the database.
Once I fill in again the data type that I am showing, the new values are there, I don´t need extra rendering.
Anyway, I was following the same steps, just for curiosity, and in other cases, I don´t get the rendering working. 
Even if my problem is solved, I would like to see one rendering working!
If anybody could tell me what is wrong with my code, it would be helpful in the future.

Thanks!